# Using FormData object in jQuery ajax request makes page redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, multipartform-data, form-data

I have been using the following piece of jQuery ajax in my website to submit form data to the server without redirecting the page.

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    const form = $("#submitableform");
    form.submit((event) => {
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(form).attr('method'),
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            dataType : 'json',
            data: $(form).serialize(),
            success: (result) => formSuccessFunction(result),
            error: (xhr, resp, text) => {
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

Everything has been working fine. I can submit the form, the page doesn't redirect and I can view all my data in the server app and the json response is sent back the client.

I now want to upload a thumbnail image with this form data. I found that I can use the FormData object to submit a multipart-formdata. This seemed to be what I might want.

I updated my jQuery call to the following:

```js
$(document).ready(() => {
    const form = $("#submitableform");
    form.onsubmit((event) => {
        let formData = new FormData(this);
        event.preventDefault();
        $.ajax({
            type: $(form).attr('method'),
            url: $(form).attr('action'),
            processData: false,
            contentType: false,
            data: formData,
            success: (result) => formSuccessFunction(result),
            error: (xhr, resp, text) => {
                console.log(xhr, resp, text);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

The form data still find its way to the server but now the page redirects to the page in the url. I cannot figure out why at all.

Also regarding the file I want to upload - only the filename is uploaded. Is this right? It's years since I have done it and I can't remember that one :)

Does anybody have any clues as to why this small change now makes my ajax request.....not an ajax request.

Thanks in advance.

(PS I have not shown my html as this has not changed at all and the original request worked. All the input field and form ids etc are exactly the same.)

Comment: you might be missing enctype="multipart/form-data" attribute in the form tag

Comment: Actually i did try this but it then just sends no data at all :)

Comment: any console errors?

Comment: wierdly the console error is that the encoding type must include multipart/form-data, however if I do this it just doesnt include data and it still redirects anyway.

Comment: Your problem is caused by using arrow functions where arrow functions aren't needed. (in addition to the incorrect method name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> The form data still find its way to the server but now the page redirects to the page in the url. I cannot figure out why at all.

In the first handler you are using:

```
form.submit((event) => {
```

This is the [.submit()](https://api.jquery.com/submit/) method to handle the

> .on( "submit", handler )

In your second fragment, instead you are using:

```
form.onsubmit((event) => {
```

The **onsubmit** is not a jQuery method hence your problem.

A second issue is related to this line:

```
let formData = new FormData(this);
```

Change it to:

```
let formData = new FormData(event.target);
```

The **this** keyword in your function context is not the current form but the default window object.

Comment: I had originally changed this out of desperate experimentation. I had changed it back already and it still doesn't work :/

Comment: as i said, I had changed this as an experiment and changed it back already. This is not the cause unfortunately

Comment: I have no doubts you are experiencing problems. Please can you write in your console **$("#submitableform").submit** and **$("#submitableform").onsubmit**  You will appreciate the difference. Thanks

Comment: I know that onsubmit doesnt work, I stopped trying to use this and I have been using submit. I am still having issues, but unfortunately this is not the root cause. but thanks anyway

Comment: Sorry, another hint: instead of **this** can you try **event.target**. **this** in your context refers to window object and not to your form. Let me know

Comment: Ah ok I did not realise this. I changed this and now the page is not redirected, however there is no data. But...I realised that I thought there is no data because I am debugging the server controller in node.js. Then it dawned on me that node express bodyparser does not automatically handle multipart requests and so i get an empty body. I think I may have got this working ages ago at one point and just tweaked it until nothing worked haha.  Thanks for your direction :)

Comment: Pleased to help you